# module "QtNetwork" is not installed

Tags: qt5, c++14, qnetworkaccessmanager

Here is the complete content of my .pro file (I have specified to add the network module):

```
QT += quick virtualkeyboard network

# You can make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

CONFIG += c++14

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp

RESOURCES += qml.qrc \
    resources/icon.qrc

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules in Qt Creator's code model
QML_IMPORT_PATH =

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules just for Qt Quick Designer
QML_DESIGNER_IMPORT_PATH =

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

However, when I use the QNetwork module in my QML file like this:

```
import QtNetwork 2.15
```

I am pointed out with the issue:

```
QML module not found (QNetwork)
Import paths:E:/Qt/5.15.2/msvc2019/qml
For qmake projects, use the QML_IMPORT_PATH variable to add import paths.
For Qbs projects, declare and set a qmllmportPaths property in your product to add import paths.
For qmlproject projects, use the importPaths property to add import paths.
For CMake projects, make sure QML_IMPORT_PATH variable is in CMakeCache.txt.
For qmlRegister.. calls, make sure that you define the Module URl as a string literal.
```

I checked folder '**E:\Qt\5.15.2\msvc2019**', and indeed, I did not find any files related to the QNetwork module.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6tWA.png)

What is going on? How should I use this module?

I have tried various solutions found online, but many of them are aimed at Visual Studio IDE. In reality, I am using **Windows 10 22H2 with QT 5.15, MSVC2019 32bit** compiler, and my Integrated Development Environment (IDE) is **QT Creator**.

#### 2024.3.29 Update

After encountering the issue, I have updated QT to the latest version and checked the installation status of the related components. Below is the installation status of QT:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMx7t.png)

Comment: Did you check this, https://forum.qt.io/topic/143956/module-qtnetwork-is-not-installed/3

Comment: @matt Yes,I have already tried, but it didn't work, and I haven't figured out what the issue is. As a QML newcomer, I'm a bit confused about what's going on. Judging from the contents of the folder, I only have the QT C++ Network module files, such as:
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QNetworkReply>
However, I do not have the relevant QML modules, such as:
import QtNetwork 2.15
Emphasis: I indeed could not find the corresponding physical files!

Comment: Shouldn't `QQmlApplicationEngine {
    qmlProtectModule("Qt.Network", 1);
}` be in your .pro file?

Comment: @matt I have already tried it, and it did not work, I'm sure!

Comment: @matt The code I'm showing is the most original code where the problem occurred. I've researched and tried basically all the information I could find. It seems to be of little use, and I'm not clear on what the issue is. Moreover, when I compile with the C++ Network module, there are no errors, but I get the following message:
**qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket::connectToHostEncrypted: TLS initialization failed**
I'm puzzled as to why I can't use anything related to networking. Is it related to my use of a VPN?

Comment: This looks like a totally different error. I think what you need to do is to create a complete example. eg. .pro and accompanying qml file that can reproduce the problem. I wouldn't be surprised if you're not expected to use the QNetwork module directly from QML. So maybe if you show what you want to do somebody can help point you in the right direction. Did you check this, https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlnetworkaccessmanagerfactory.html ?

Comment: The ssl error seems to be something completely different, https://forum.qt.io/topic/95700/qsslsocket-tls-initialization-failed/6